# Removing fixed phase offset noise

Tags: noise, qpsk, pll

This feels like a real basic question but I'm struggling to find a clear answer.

I have PSK signal that subjected to a fixed phase shift noise, introduced between the transmitter and receiver - so the received signal has a constant phase shift from the expected signal without noise.

The question is how to compensate for this - on the constellation diagram in Matlab the constellations are rotated, but in the physical system I understand that there will be a Phase Locked Loop in the receiver.  Won't this simply lock onto the zero crossings in the phase shifted signal, effectively removing the phase offset noise.

What am I missing?

What other options are there for removing the fixed phase offset noise?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this ***purely*** a synchronization issue?  A spurious constant phase offset is the same as a delay mismatch.  And synchronization of receiver to the transmitter is how we deal with a delay or phase mismatch.  I had always thunked that sync'ing can be done with frame sync words, sometimes called "preambles".

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense!